# System.AggregateException at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskExceptionHolder.Finalize()

Tags: c#, exception, task-parallel-library, aggregate, crash

**Update:**

Adding TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning solved the issue but is this a good approach ? If not, what is the best solution to get over this exception ?

There is an issue i am trying to troubleshoot. I have implemented the suggestions that were provided in StackOverFlow but those have not helped solve the issue. I have used other alternatives like ContinuwWith option instead of Task.WaitAll by attaching the extension method. This did not help either .

I have put Ex.handle { } and i have tried throw ex in the Catch(aggrgateException ex) in the exceptions but that did not help to catch the actual exception.

I have only .Net 4.0 installed so i cannot try the .Net 4.5 resolution to solve this

The exception that i have been getting all the time is

> "System.AggregateException:" The task's exception was not observed either by waiting on the task or accessing the Exception property "

After this it simply kills worker process and the App crashes and i see an entry in the EventViewer

Any help here here will be appreciated.

We have the below code:

```
Task<List<MyBusinessObject>>[] tasks = new Task<List<MyBusinessObject>>[MyCollection.Count];

for (int i = 0; i < MyCollection.Count; i++)
{
    MyDTO dto = new MyDTO();

     --Some Property Assignment for the MyDTO object--

    tasks[i] = Task<List<MyBusinessObject>>.Factory.StartNew(MyDelegate, dto)

}

try
{
    Task.WaitAll(tasks);
}
catch (AggregateException e)
{
    AddToLogFile("Exceptions thrown by WaitAll() : ");

    for (int j = 0; j < e.InnerExceptions.Count; j++)
    {
        AddToLogFile(e.InnerExceptions[j].ToString());

    }
}  
catch(Exception ex)

{  

AddToLogFile(ex.Message);

}
```

### Second Alternative

```
public Static Class Extensions
{
 public static void LogExceptions(this Task<List<<MyBusinessObject>> task)
        {
            task.ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                var aggException = t.Exception.Flatten();
                foreach (var exception in aggException.InnerExceptions)
                {
                    AddToLogFile("Task Exception: " + exception.Message);

                }
            },
            TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
        }
}
//In a different class call the extension method after starting the new tasks
Task<List<MyBusinessObject>>[] tasks = new Task<List<MyBusinessObject>>[MyCollection.Count];

for (int i = 0; i < MyCollection.Count; i++)
{
    MyDTO dto = new MyDTO();

     --Some Property Assignment for the MyDTO object--

    tasks[i] = Task<List<MyBusinessObject>>.Factory.StartNew(MyDelegate, dto).LogExceptions()

}
```

Comment: What is the `InnerException` of the `AggregateException`?

Comment: It was System.Net.WebException : The request was aborted. The request was cancelled at System.Net.HTTPWebRequest.BeginGetRequestStream........... at the end  it says at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

Comment: It's unrelated but you should not flatten. Just log the AggEx. That logs maximum information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating a new tasks for each iteration all at one time, i created the new task for 100 tasks every time. I then waited till all the tasks were complete and spwaned off another 100 tasks till all the tasks were finished

int count = Mycollection.Count();
                    Task>[] tasks;

```
        int i = 0;
                int j;
                while (i < count)
                {
                    j = 0;
                    tasks = new Task<List<MyBusinessObject>>[nbrOfTasks];
                    foreach (var p in Mycollection.Skip(i).Take(nbrOfTasks))
                    {
                        MyRequestDto dto = new MyRequestDto ();
                    --Some Proerty Assignment
                        tasks[j] = Task<List<MyBusinessObject>>.Factory.StartNew(MyDelegate, dto);
                        i++;
                        j++;
                    }

        try
                    {
                        // Wait for all the tasks to finish. 
                        if (tasks != null && tasks.Count() > 0)
                        {
                            tasks = tasks.Where(t => t != null).ToArray();
                            Task.WaitAll(tasks);
                        }
                    }
        catch (AggregateException e)
                    {
            }
```

This is to do with the memory avaiable to service multiple tasks. If the required RAM was not available to service the concurrent tasks along the way, the App Would just crash.That is why it is best to spawn limited nbr of tasks. Instead of spwaning multiple and leaving it to the threadpool to manage.